# Omit NA values from prcomp() in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, numpy, rpy2

```
import numpy
import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr('stats')
r = robjects.r
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

a = numpy.array( [ [1, 5, numpy.nan, 4, 5], [2, 6, 8, 7, 8] ] )
b = numpy.array( [ [1, 5, 8, 4, 5], [2, 6, 8, 7, 8] ] )

std = r.sd( a[0], **{'na.rm': 'TRUE'} )              # works fine
pca = stats.prcomp( b )                              # works fine
pca = stats.prcomp( a )                              # error
pca = stats.prcomp( a, **{'na.rm': 'TRUE'} )         # error
pca = stats.prcomp( a, **{'na.action': 'na.omit'} )  # error
```

The last three prcomp() calls give me this error:

```
Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

I have Googled a bunch, can't figure out how to properly use na.action (or other means) to handle NA values in prcomp() via rpy2.  I'm hoping it's just a syntax issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The "na.action" must be a function, not a string with a function name.
The following might do the trick:

```
pca = stats.prcomp( a, **{'na.action': stats.na_omit} )
```

Note that NA != NaN. From your example:

```
ar = robjects.vectors.Matrix(a)

print(ar)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5  NaN    4    5
[2,]    2    6    8    7    8
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That syntax gives me the same error as before and I tried some variants with no luck. Any further ideas?